# mysql where clause trim notworking

Tags: mysql

```
+-------------+----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| tutorial_id | tutorial_title | tutorial_author | submission_date |
+-------------+----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|           3 | JAVA Tutorial  | Sanjay          | 2007-05-21      |
+-------------+----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

Query

```
SELECT * from tutorials_tbl WHERE TRIM(tutorial_title)='JAVATutorial';
```

Returning no records found

Comment: `JAVATutorial` or `JAVA Tutorial` in where ?

Comment: Trim does not mean what you think it does.

Comment: Should be `SELECT * from tutorials_tbl WHERE TRIM(tutorial_title)='JAVA Tutorial';`

Comment: in where input customer will post like JAVATutorial

Comment: `TRIM()` removes the leading and trailing spaces - it **doesn't** remove whitespace inside of text.

Comment: @Bharanikumar then you can use `Replace(tutorial_title, ' ', '')`

Comment: Try to use Replace instead.

Comment: trim will eliminate front and back of the word only

Answer (score 3):

Try to Use `REPLACE` instead of `TRIM`.

```
SELECT * from tutorials_tbl WHERE replace(tutorial_title,' ','')='JAVATutorial'
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need `Replace` instead of `Trim`

```
SELECT * from tutorials_tbl WHERE Replace(tutorial_title, ' ', '')='JAVATutorial';
```

[**DETAILS**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html)

Answer (score 1):

**TRIM** only remove non visible characters (such as spaces, tabulations, break lines, ...) at the begining or at the end. If you want to other spaces you have to use other commands such as **Replace**

```
SELECT * from tutorials_tbl WHERE REPLACE(tutorial_title)='JAVATutorial';
```